# Problems calling a function inside a listener (onClick)

Tags: javascript, function, phaser-framework

I've looked around on here for an answer to this but I can't find anything that works.

Basically I'm making a tower defence game. Each tower is dynamically created and is onClick enabled. Inside the onClick listener I am trying to call a method within the class.

e.g a player clicks the tower and can choose upgrades

However the method within the listener is outputing undefined function. I know this is clearly something to do with my scope. But I can't figure out what I'm missing?

Surely it should be something like:

```
someListener: function(){
  this.game.doSomeOtherFunction();
}
```

I've tried a console.log and someListener is definitely being called, but the method inside is undefined.

Thanks,

Comment: Inside an event listener, this refers to the element on which the event occurred, not the outer scope. You need a closure that saves the scope you want in a variable.

Comment: Wow, that makes a lot of sense... Thanks. Ok I will have a look at closures. :)

Answer (score 5):

Its not working because `this` changes context accordingly within a callback. You can do something like this:

```
var self = this;
...
someListener: function(){
  self.game.doSomeOtherFunction(); 
}
...
```

Or simply you could also do this:

```
someListener: (function () {
       var callback = function(){
          this.game.doSomeOtherFunction(); 
       }
     return callback.bind(this);
}())
```

I hope it helps.